# Passing a List to DB and join a property with a Table

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, list, c#-4.0

I have got a List of `Sometype`. `Sometype` has got two properties

`Key`

`ModificationDate`

Now i have a table in my DB called Measures.It also has got these fields as columns.

I just want to get all the measures (keys should match)and 
Modiciationdate(from List) > ModiciationDate(from table).

Right now i am fetching all measures from my table and checking it in my app .How can i avoid that?

**P.S** I am using Nhibernate.`Sometype` is actually an entity in my app.I also have another entity mapped to the Measures Table(Both cannot be the same as it has got some additional properties as well)

**EDIT** what i need is, If the list i have is in some sort of temptable then the query will be

`select * from Measures A join TempTable B on A.Key=B.Key and A.ModificationDate < B.ModificationDate`.

But can it be done without inserting all the values from list to some #table?

Comment: Isn't this just a standard query to the db "WHERE Measures.Key IN ( ... )" ?

Comment: that's what i am doing right now.But that is going to fecth all the measures matching the list which is supplied in the IN clause.I need to have one more condiftion to be satisfied. the modification date to be greater.How do you do that rather than picking all records and checking the condition inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this approach.

In code, write a method to generate desire sql.

```
    private string BuildSQL(List<SomeType> param)
            {
                string res = string.Empty;

                if (param != null && param.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SomeType type in param)
                    {
                        res += " (A.Key='" + type.Key + "' AND A.ModificationDate < '" + type.ModificationDate + "') OR";
                    }
                }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
{
res = res.Substring(0, res.Length - 3);
}
                return res;
            }
```

and then, just pass this sql into call function (maybe DAO class):

string sqlString= "select * from Measures A where " + BuildSQL(param);
OdbcCommand.CommandText = sqlString;
OdbcCommand.executeNonQuery();

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before.  What I have used in the past is a function on the database end, that can take a list of characters (let's say, csv) and turns them into temporary Table Variable that you can join against.

An example of this function is:

```
FUNCTION ListToTable
(  @SEP char(1),
   @LST varchar(max)
) RETURNS @TBL TABLE (idx int, txt varchar(max)) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @IX int, @POS int, @COUNT int, @STR varchar(max)
   SET @POS = 1
   SET @IX = 1
   SET @COUNT = 0
   WHILE @IX > 0
   BEGIN
      SET @IX = charindex(@SEP, @LST, @POS)
      IF @IX > 0
         SET @STR = substring(@LST, @POS, @IX - @POS)
      ELSE
         SET @STR = substring(@LST, @POS, len(@LST))
      SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
      INSERT @TBL (idx, txt) VALUES(@COUNT, @STR)
      SET @POS = @IX + 1
   END
   RETURN
END
```

Then when you perform your query you can say:

```
SELECT * FROM
Measures A 
INNER JOIN
ListToTable(',', '1,1,2,3,5,8,...,21')  B 
ON A.Key=B.Key 
AND A.ModificationDate < B.ModificationDate.
```

If you need to do some casting against the table to make the IDs ints, or whatever; that's fine.  I'm not sure if you can get this into HQL, but it works fine as a query.

Comment: i too thought about this as you can see from my EDIT in Question.but it not sounding very elegent one and also i need it to be done from Nhibernate..

Comment: Doing an 'Where In (#,#,...,#)' conditional has a very real limit.  Unless you use a memory table, or temp table setup; when you hit that limit your query will stop working anyway.